# Word Embeddings fastText in 50 dimension

Tags: word-embeddings, reference-request

Is there a fastText embedding in 50 dimensions? I'm aware of GloVe embedding is dimensions (50, 100, 200, 300) dimensions. I am trying to sentiment analysis with a very small dataset.

If there is please can anyone provide a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58930298/reducing-size-of-facebooks-fasttext-word2vec

Link to the official documentation: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

Installation instructions: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python#installation